# kohana 3.0 delete_all() failure

Tags: kohana-3

I have a kohana 3 based application, and I want to delete all entries based on some conditions. The problem is that the `delete_all()` method doesn't delete anything at all.

The code:

```
 $user_preferences = Model::factory('userpreferences')->get_user($user)->delete_all();
```

Though if I put :

```
 $user_preferences = Model::factory('userpreferences')->get_user($user)->find_all();
```

there are retrieved some registries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the database connection set to autocommit? You might need to manually begin/commit a transaction to make your changes persist.